# Is there a method to get the Total JDBC connections?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have a jabber bot that connects to a database to gather data and report it. In case a connection goes down it is re-established and DB connection is re-initiated. Is there a method that I can call to list all the JDBC open and closed connections?

Comment: I don't think so - certainly `DriverManager` makes no mention of one. Providing you manage the connections you make correctly you shouldn't need this.

Comment: You may use Connection Pool which automatically manages the connections based on their open state.

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If your database is Oracle, you can query the database sessions using the `v$session` view. For example with this query:

```
column sid format 9999
column serial# format 9999999
column username format a8
column machine format a15
column osuser format a6
column program format a12

SELECT sid, serial#, username, machine, osuser, status, program, TO_CHAR(logon_time, 'MM-DD HH24:MI') logon_time
 FROM v$session 
 WHERE username IS NOT NULL AND machine IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY logon_time;
```

The rows starting with `column` are not significant if you run the query from Java. They are formatting the result table if you test the query using Sql*Plus before incorporating it into Java.